# Polymer app-route redirect

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using `<app-route>` in Polymer. Everything works fine, except redirection. I've read https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/routing, the explanation seems to be clear, but for some reason it doesn't work the way I would want it.

Somewhere down in the view I have an element...

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'user-auth',
        responseHandler: function(event) {
            var token = event.detail.response.d.token;
            if (token != '') {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
                this.set('route.path', '/hello');
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, it redirects to `/x/y/z/hello` instead of `/hello` as an absolute url. How could I make the redirect absolute?

Comment: Hi Andrew! Almost ran in the same problem as you. I think that the problem is with the "this" itself. Try targeting the element through a document.querySelector or document.getElementById, and once you grabbed it, apply the this.set. That's what I've just done.

Comment: Also, I'm seeing right now that the "this" is alone. You need to target it using this.$.elementId. Or do a document.querySelector to fetch it. Let me know your results.

Answer (score -3):

Without the `<app-route>` it is hard to tell.

Another (dirty) option would be:

```
<style>
  #redirect {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

...

<a id="redirect" href="/hello"></a>

...

<script>
  ...
  // at the place where you want to redirect
  this.$.redirect.click();
  ...
</script>
```